# CSS styling changes when tunneling my website with Cloudflare

Tags: html, css, web, cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

This is how the website looks directly in my localhost:

[LOCALHOST DIRECTLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsQVR.png)

And here via Cloudflare:

[CLOUDFLARE TUNNEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JSNI.png)

It looks like the metrics change and the values themself, because as you can notice the color fade of the navbar is different, which means 200px (box-shadow: 2px 1px 200px -88px white inset) aren't the same in localhost directly than via Cloudflare. Does someone knows why is this happening? Is there a way to fix it? Because even if the Cloudflare is the one people will see when they log in my website, I need to develop it using the localhost view because changes on files are shown instantly.

I'm using a view engine EJS, node and express for the server btw. Thanks.

I don't even know where to start to fix it, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Please confirm your browser's zoom level is the same for both URLs

Comment: You could try to post your experiment right here in a code snippet, and see how it renders! From the image alone we can't really see what could be the reason.